# Need Help in Writing VIEW in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have 2 tables in SQL Server, one is called `PO RECEIPT` table and the other is `Move Order` table.

I need to write a query to insert data into `Receipt` table which is working fine. Receipt Number will be unique in `Receipt` table because it is a primary key and auto increment, e.g, for `Receipt` number 1 I have 2000 quantity received (it is a column).

If I want to move 500 to the move and another 500 next time for same receipt number. Now I want to write a VIEW which will add up move quantity in the `Move Order` table grouped by `Receipt Number` and will minus this quantity from the quantity received column in the `Receipt` table.

Currently I write this view which is working fine for same `Receipt Number` but when we have different `Receipt Number` in the `Move Order` table it generates an error. The view is

```
select distinct 
    [5_PO_RECEIPT_TABLE_DATABASE].[Part Number],
    [5_PO_RECEIPT_TABLE_DATABASE].[Receipt Number],
    (select sum([Move_Order].[Move Quantity]) 
     from [Move_Order] 
     group by [Move_Order].[Receipt Number]),
    [5_PO_RECEIPT_TABLE_DATABASE].[Quantity Received] + [Move_Order].[Move Quantity] as TotalQuantity 
from 
    [5_PO_RECEIPT_TABLE_DATABASE]
inner join 
    [Move_Order] on [5_PO_RECEIPT_TABLE_DATABASE].[Receipt Number] = [Move_Order].[Receipt Number]
```

The error generated by above view is

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is pretty clear: your subquery (the `(select sum(..) from [Move_order]....` returns multiple values - and you cannot have a subquery return multiple values if you use it in the `SELECT` list of columns...

Most likely, you just want to the `SUM([Move_Order].[Move Quantity])` for that one `Move_Order` you're currently looking at - so you need to change your subquery to take that into account:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    rcpt.[Part Number],
    rcpt.[Receipt Number],
    (SELECT SUM(m.[Move Quantity]) 
     FROM [Move_Order] m
     WHERE m.[Receipt Number] = rcpt.[Receipt Number]),
    rcpt.[Quantity Received] + mo.[Move Quantity] AS TotalQuantity 
FROM
    [5_PO_RECEIPT_TABLE_DATABASE] rcpt
INNER JOIN 
    [Move_Order] mo ON rcpt.[Receipt Number] = mo.[Receipt Number]
```

I also use meaningful / self-explanatory **table aliases** to make a query a lot more readable ....

So now, your subquery will sum up all the `[Move Quantity]` values from the `[Move Order]` table for that one `[Receipt Number]` that is currently being processed.

Answer (score 1):

Also in SQLServer2005+ you can use option with [OVER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       rcpt.[Part Number],
       rcpt.[Receipt Number], 
       SUM(mo.[Move Quantity]) OVER(PARTITION BY rcpt.[Receipt Number]),
       rcpt.[Quantity Received] + mo.[Move Quantity] AS TotalQuantity
FROM [5_PO_RECEIPT_TABLE_DATABASE] rcpt
  INNER JOIN [Move_Order] mo ON rcpt.[Receipt Number] = mo.[Receipt Number]
```

BTW, I think DISTINCT keyword is excessive in this case because your values in the TotalQuantity column is differ